# Custom BaseAdapter null pointer

Tags: android

I get a null ponter at `lv1.setAdapter(myAdapter)` and I can't figure out why. can someone see whats wrong?

I am trying to achieve a two-line list

**MyActivity.class**

```
final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
          Log.d("",topicTitle.toString() + "----------" +  topicAuthor.toString()); //not null
          MyCustomBaseAdapter myAdapter =  new MyCustomBaseAdapter(DiscussionTopics.this, topicTitle , topicAuthor);
          lv1.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

**MyCustomBaseAdapter.class**

```
public class MyCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static ArrayList<String> topics;
    private static ArrayList<String> author;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public MyCustomBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> topics, ArrayList<String> author ) {
        this.topics = topics;
        this.author = author;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.author = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.author);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.title.setText(topics.get(position));
        holder.author.setText(author.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }
    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView author;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return topics.size();
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return topics.get(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you help us out a little more and give the line number that giving the NPE?

Comment: @FrankSposaro it occurs at the line `lv1.setAdapter(myAdapter);`

Comment: I guess `lv1` is `null` because you are not setting any content on the activity... we've seen a dozen of posts just like this in the past days

Comment: the adapter is good to do will not give null pointer, the lv1.setAdapter(null) is also a valid case; So your list view id might have some problem. is the id exist in xml to .. might using listActivity so use android.R.id.list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your never getting a handler on `R.id.ListView01`

```
final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
```

Make sure that your calling setContentView() before this line and giving it the layout that contains `R.id.ListView01`